# Можно ли использовать конструкцию if...else в setter'e?

Tags: java

Всем привет! Простите за нубский вопрос, но можно ли использовать условие в сеттере?
В решаемой задаче получаемое значение должно соответствовать некоему условию, в противном случае должно подставляться дефолтное значение. Я хочу сделать так, но не уверен, что это правильно:

```
public void setHouseName(String houseName) {
    if (houseName.length()<4 || houseName.length()>20){
        this.houseName = "House#" + collectorNumber;
    }
    else{
        this.houseName = houseName;
    }
}
```

Comment: это ж обычные методы... а значит можно

Comment: Конечно можно и даже нужно. Для того они и есть, а "пустые" сеттеры и геттеры как по мне мусор!

Comment: @0xdb, поправил.

Comment: сеттеров/геттеров в хорошо спроектированных классах очень мало. если у вас их много, то это скорей всего проблема в дизайне.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, конечно можно. Только это будет сеттер, который устанавливает значение. Геттер наоборот, возвращает его

```
public void setHouseName(String houseName) {
    if (houseName.length() < 4 || houseName.length() > 20) {
        this.houseName = "House#" + collectorNumber;
    }
    else {
        this.houseName = houseName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Ты точно отличаешь getter от setter'а?
2. В обоих можно, т. к. это просто обычные функции. Теоретически, для того и нужны.
3. Код в вопросе неверный, поскольку присваивание `this.houseName = houseName;` происходит безусловно. Нужно оставить присваивания только в ветвях if'а, а последнее убрать.

Comment: Да, последнее тут не нужно. Это просто описка. Спасибо за замечание. Сейчас поправлю код.